# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax when create trigger

Tags: mysql

I have faced this problem when I created an after insert trigger. I know this is an syntax error, but I don't know how to fix it in my SQL.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5

**Here is my trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_to_student_table
AFTER INSERT ON user
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE v_UserID INTEGER;
SET @v_UserID := (Select Max(UserID) from user where Type="Student");
INSERT INTO student (StudentID,TutorID)VALUES (v_UserID, NULL);
END
```

Comment: I think its 'DECLARE @v_UserID INTEGER;'  you miss the '@' also in the insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a `delimiter`

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER insert_to_student_table
AFTER INSERT ON user
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE v_UserID INTEGER;
SET v_UserID = (Select Max(UserID) from user where Type="Student");
INSERT INTO student (StudentID,TutorID)VALUES (v_UserID, NULL);
END;//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still got the same error after tried this. :(

Comment: Are you running this trigger on CLI or on some other tools.

Comment: In PHP myadmin you have an option to set the delimiter, check that part and set a delimiter and then remove the delimiter from the above code it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked immediately after I remove the delimiter check in Phpmyadmin.